# Simply want to compare an item but get a UndefinedVariableError

Tags: python, pandas, ascii

I'm writing a simple script to translate an input message into a series of decimal ascii codes and keep getting `UndefinedVariableError` and can't figure out why it's happening. Here's my code:

```py
def convert_text_dec():
    message_to_encode = input('Enter a message: ')
    glossary = pd.read_excel('ascii-table.xls', skiprows=[0,1],
                             usecols=['dex', 'symbol'], nrows=256)
    ascii_message = []    

    letters = list(message_to_encode)
    for item in letters:
        letter = glossary.query(f'symbol=={item}')['dex'].iloc[0]
        ascii_message.append(letter)

    print(ascii_message)
```

In the same file I have a pretty much identical function that does the opposite and it works without issue, but when I try to run `convert_text_dec` and for example enter 'hello' as a message I get the following error:

```
  File "F:/python/binary_to_text/bin2text.py", line 52, in <module>
    convert_text_dec()

  File "F:/python/binary_to_text/bin2text.py", line 47, in convert_text_dec
    letter = glossary.query(f'symbol=={item}')['dex'].iloc[0]

...
...
UndefinedVariableError: name 'h' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you might want to include the complete stack trace.  not seeing an h referenced at all in the code example.

Comment: Try to quote the `{item}` with `"`,  so it becomes `letter = glossary.query(f'symbol=="{item}"')['dex'].iloc[0]`

Comment: @LhasaDad , the 'h' is the first letter of 'hello'. For some reason the `query` treats it as variable name even though I'm using f-string and want to get a value of the item.

Comment: `pandas.query` is trying to evaluate the expression `symbol==h`

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks mate! This worked!

Comment: @AndrejKesely You should post that as an answer and explain why it's necessary.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use `list(message_to_encode)`. `for item in message_to_encode:` will loop over the letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
for item in letters:
    letter = glossary.query(f'symbol=={item}')['dex'].iloc[0]
    ascii_message.append(letter)
```

you are creating the query for every letter, eg. `symbol==h`. Pandas is trying to evaluate the query but variable `h` isn't defined anywhere.

Quoting the `{item}` with `"` should correct the problem:

```
letter = glossary.query(f'symbol=="{item}"')['dex'].iloc[0]
```